# Irreversible isobaric process paradox

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility

We know from the First Principle that:

$$W = Q - \Delta U$$

Suppose that we know the initial and final temperature of an isobaric irreversible process; then we can deduct many things:

$$\Delta U = n c_V \Delta T$$

and for an isobaric process: $$Q = n c_p \Delta T$$

and can't we always deduct the work as: $$W = Q - \Delta U = n \left( c_p - c_V \right) \Delta T = n R \Delta T$$

?

Is my thought process correct? If indeed it is, then what's the difference in terms of efficiency between a reversible and an irreversible isobaric process that operate in the same range of temperatures? I thought that at least the work should have been different...

Answer (score 3):

An "irreversible isobaric process" is the term we use to describe a situation in which a gas is at an initial pressure $P_0$ and we suddenly drop (or raise) the force per unit area exerted on the gas by the inner face of the piston to $P_1\neq P_0$, and hold it at this value while the piston moves and the gas re-equilibrates.  Under these circumstances, the work done is $$W=P_1(V_1-V_0)=P_1\left(\frac{nRT_1}{P_1}-\frac{nRT_0}{P_0}\right)=nR\left(T_1-\frac{P_1}{P_0}T_0\right)$$Note that, only at a single  instant of time during this irreversible change in state was the gas really at its initial pressure $P_0$.  Therefore, grammatically, it is not quite really correct to call this an isobaric irreversible process.  However, we still do, and we know what we mean.

The change in internal energy, which depends only on the two end points is still $$\Delta U=nC_v(T_1-T_0)$$But, the heat added is now:$$Q=\Delta U+W=nC_p(T_1-T_0)+nR\left(1-\frac{P_1}{P_0}\right)T_0$$

If $P_1$ were equal to $P_0$ (and the system were merely receiving heating or cooling by the surroundings at the constant external force), then, even for irreversible heating or cooling, the equations you wrote for the work, heat, and change in internal energy would still be correct.  This is one of those interesting cases where, irrespective of the path reversibility (provided the external force is constant), the heat, work, and changes in entropy and internal energy *of the system* would be the same.  However, any entropy generated within the system in the process would be transferred from the system to the reservoirs that are being used to bring about the heating or cooling.  So, the entropy of the combination of system and  surroundings would increase for an irreversible heating or cooling path.

Comment: I came across this when researching irreversible isobaric processes. While I agree with your answer, I wonder if the only irreversible isobaric process involves a sudden pressure drop. That example involves mechanical disequilibrium. How about thermal disequilibrium, such as due to a finite temperature difference between the surroundings and the system during the expansion?

Comment: @BobD Yes, you can certainly do that too, plus, in that case, if the rate of heat transfer is high enough, the gas will deform very rapidly and create mechanical disequilibrium (even if the external pressure is held constant at the original gas pressure).  In such a case, viscous stresses within the gas would make up the difference.

Comment: Hi Chet. I’ve thought more about this.  You say the work and heat are the same for the reversible and irreversible process as long as the external pressure is constant.  Yet looking at the equations, if say $P_{1}<P_0$ (sudden drop in external pressure) the work, heat for the same initial and final temperature will be the greater for the irreversible process than the reversible process where $P_{1}=P_0$.

Comment: Seems like this would require that the final volume $V_1$ be greater for the irreversible process for the same temperature change. Considering only the $PV$ diagram, the work will only be the same for the reversible and irreversible process for the same final volume. What am I missing?

Comment: @BobD Not if, in the irreversible expansion, you do as I described, and initially drop the externally applied pressure to a new lower value, and then hold it at value throughout the expansion.

Comment: If $P_{1}=P_0$ and the gas expands reversibly the process is reversible and if $P_{1}<P_0$ the process is irreversible, correct?

Comment: Yes.  That’s correct.

Comment: OK. Then doesn't the first equation for work give us a higher value if $P_{1}<P_{0}$ (the irreversible expansion process) than if $P_{1}=P_2$ (the reversible expansion process)? And doesn't the last equation for heat also give us a higher value for the irreversible expansion process than for the reversible expansion process?

Comment: Yes, for the same temperature change, the irreversible work is higher and the necessary heat to be added is also higher.  Interesting.  Well, at least, for the irreversible path, the entropy change is higher.

Comment: Of course, for a reversible isobaric expansion at constant temperature, the amount of work is zero, so any amount of work for an irreversible isobaric expansion at constant temperature would be more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113563/discussion-between-bob-d-and-chet-miller).

Comment: Hi Chet. The nuisance is back again. In your third equation, shouldn't $nC_{p}(T_{1}-T_{o})$  be $nC_{v}(T_{1}-T_{o})$? And isn't the third equation of the OP only applicable to a reversible isobaric process?

Comment: My 3rd equation is correct.  I added and subtracted $nRT_0$ from the work in the previous equation.  When $P_1=P_0$, $Q=nC_p\Delta T$ as expected.  The 3rd equation in the OP is applicable to any process, such as a chemical reaction. in which $P=P_1=P_0$ throughout the process, even if the reaction proceeds at finite rate (irreversibley), and the initial and final states are equilibrium states.

Comment: Sorry I missed that change in your work equation. But I'm still uneasy with the OP third equation. Doesn't the use of $C_p$ assume the gas pressure is constant, which would only be the case for a reversible process?

Comment: @BobD If you hold the external pressure equal to the initial pressure, if doesn't matter how fast (irreversibly) the heat is added.  The change in enthalpy is still equal to $nC_p\Delta T$, and is equal to the amount of heat added.

Comment: Ah yes, and enthalpy is a state function. Thus your conclusion that if $P_{1}=P_{0}$  work, heat and internal energy change are the same for both the reversible and irreversible process. Only entropy of surroundings is greater. Which leaves me with one final question. Are there any practical consequences of the entropy generated if an irreversible isobaric process is part of a cycle where all the other processes are reversible?

Comment: @BobD  Loss of work that could have been done?

Comment: Hmm. Since no work is lost in the irreversible isobaric process I don't see how work will be lost by including it in an otherwise reversible cycle. This reminds me of our previous discussion of an irreversible isochoric process and how it had no effect on cycle work. I will have to think about this more. Thanks for your time.